# "Unsupported parameters for (ecs_taskdefinition) module: cpu,launch_type,memory Supported parameters include:

Tags: ansible

getting "Unsupported parameters for (ecs_taskdefinition) module: cpu,launch_type,memory Supported parameters include: arn,aws_access_key,aws_secret_key,containers,ec2_url,family,network_mode,profile,region,revision,security_token,state,task_role_arn,validate_certs,volumes"}

````
      ecs_taskdefinition:
       family: "{{ taskfamily_name }}"
#        task_role_arn: "{{ ecs_role.arn }}"
#        execution_role_arn: "{{ ecs_role.arn }}"
       containers:
        - name: "{{ container_name }}"
          essential: true
          image: "{{ image_var }}"
          portMappings:
          - containerPort: "{{ container_port }}"
            hostPort:      "{{ container_port }}"
          environment:
          - name: xyz_ENV
            value: "{{ env }}"
       launch_type: FARGATE
       cpu: "{{ cpu_var }}"
       memory: "{{ memory_var }}"
       state: present
       network_mode: awsvpc ```
````

Answer (score 0):

> cpu,launch_type,memory

Those parameters were added in ansible 2.7

You have to upgrade your ansible version or drop those params.

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ecs_taskdefinition_module.html